# Delay running of Jquery for 2 seconds after first value has been sent

Tags: jquery, ajax, delay, settimeout, intervals

```
function randomQuote () {
     $('#decoded').val($.scriptcam.getBarCode());
     var decoded = $('#decoded').val();
     if(decoded != ""){

     $("#avatar").html('<img src="database/img/picloader.gif" style="height:150px;width:150px;"/> ');
     //alert(decode);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "database/dataLog.php",
                data: {
                        decoded: decoded
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#avatar").html(data.avatar);
                    $("#profile").html(data.profile);
                    $("#log").html(data.log);
                    $("#sfx").html(data.sfx);

                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#avatar").html('<img src="database/img/avatar.jpg" style="height:150px;width:150px;"/> ');
                    $("#profile").html('');
                    $("#log").html('');
                    $("#sfx").html('');
                    }, 15000);

                }
            });

     }
```

how can i delay sending of values in jquery, the code is sending info too fast, sometimes it double or triple sends it, what i want is when the jquery got 1 value it will send it to ajax and it will not accept another value for 2 seconds. is that possible?

Comment: This library may help: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: Would this not be possible by using sheer setInterval or setTimeout functions?